# Distribute APK for an Open Beta with like unique URL or a Code system

Tags: android, beta

I am evaluating options to do a Open Beta phase via our website.

We have a registration system operational on our website.

My idea is to send au automatic Email containing an URL and a code for the Beta tester.
The Url would allow him to download the pack. The code might me incorporated in the parameters of the URL.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have tagged this question with Android, I presume you have an Android app which you would like to release for beta testing to a select number of users. I'm not sure where the registration system on your website comes into it.

The Android Developer Console allows for you to upload a signed APK for alpha or beta testing. You can choose to run either an open beta or a closed beta. The open beta allows anyone given a specific link to install your app via the play store. The closed beta only allows users with specific email addresses use your app. It sounds like the open beta option would be more appropriate in your situation.

It is not clear to me what you mean by a "code" to be given to the user. If you wish to have some control over who can access the beta, then you should choose the closed beta option in the Developer Console.

There is no reason why you would create your own distribution system for beta testing, as there is already a perfectly adequate system available through the Android Developer Console.

There are multiple tutorials, as well as extensive official documentation available, on how to publish and set up beta testing.